# Swift email format validation without using regex

Tags: ios, swift, validation, email

There is an official way to validate if an email address is valid without using regex?

I've already implemented this validation with regex:

```
public func validate(email:String)->Bool{
    let regex:String = "\\A[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\z"

    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", regex)

    return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(email)

}
```

I'm on this for a while and I'm looking for an official way to do this in swift/ios without writing my own logic, which in my opinion is more related to have bugs.

Comment: Only way to reliably verify an email address is to send a confirmation mail.

Comment: I mean validate the format.

Comment: You basically can't. Check for an "@" and some characters after and before it, everything else is potentially valid.

Comment: It's extremely hard to validate email addresses in regex. See [this article](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/) to understand why.

Comment: I agree with @luk2302, have a look at this article: [Stop Validating Email Addresses with Regex](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Comment: I don't agree with the decision of marking this question as duplicate. Can someone please reopen it? I am also looking for a way of validating email formats because our App must work offline.

Comment: @BonanzaOne as I said previously: check for an @ and check that there are *characters* after and before it. Alternatively try this regex: https://www.debuggex.com/r/aH_x42NflV8G-GS7 - not sure if that actually covers everything